# How do I get video info for Youtube Vevo Videos?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels, youtube.net-api, android-youtube-api

I was trying to play YouTube Videos outside YT player, When I was trying to download info using "http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=" for Vevo Channel videos it gives the following content!

> errordetail=0&reason=This+video+contains+content+from+VEVO.+It+is+restricted+from+playback+on+certain+sites.%3Cbr%2F%3E%3Cu%3E%3Ca+href%3D%27http%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D1G4isv_Fylg%26feature%3Dplayer_embedded%27+target%3D%27_blank%27%3EWatch+on+YouTube%3C%2Fa%3E%3C%2Fu%3E&storyboard_spec=http%3A%2F%2Fi2.ytimg.com%2Fsb%2F1G4isv_Fylg%2Fstoryboard3_L%24L%2F%24N.jpg%7C48%2327%23100%2310%2310%230%23default%23zmO7uhaupuPIrI2qBZC2EBjg2oc%7C80%2345%23131%2310%2310%232000%23M%24M%23sxd-GFqCDrqpnzGPaNdxyOtaxtU%7C160%2390%23131%235%235%232000%23M%24M%23of8CiThJl9d5Upo9rUKgWs93QyE%7C320%23180%23131%233%233%232000%23M%24M%236gImdPOIrD6Bdl5e6iePOdKSdMA&loudness=-16.4200000763&errorcode=150&status=fail

I can't do anything with it, Does anyone have any ideas for Vevo Videos?

Comment: have you got any solution for this ?

Answer (score 6):

```
http://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=yt_video_id&el=vevo&el=embedded
```

Replace `yt_video_id` with the `id` of the video you're trying to get.

Comment: its not working with "video_id=/*video_id*/&el=vevo&el=embedded"
--
There are many of the videos aren't getting the video info.
There are following videos, not getting the video info.
--
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O1_3zBUKM8
-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHue-HaXXzg
-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNu_-deVemE
but we can play this videos in some of the live application.like 
-- https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tfsapps.playtube2
-- https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/itube-playlist-management/id789819758?mt=8
--
if I want to play all the videos, so what's the solution?

Comment: @V.K. It still works. You can analyse the json file retrieved from calling the url. Google has changed it a little while ago. Sometimes the `sig` segment is already in the url, so you don't have to find the `sig` in the `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map`, just use the url.

Comment: @V.K. one more thing, if there is no `sig` segment in the url or in the `url_encoded_fmt_stream_map`, but there is a `s` segment. You need to decrypt `s`.

Comment: Can please describe the ans, in following question?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424908/vevo-videos-not-getting-videourl-from-youtube

Comment: I'm using this kind of URL also now but I can't get any resolution higher than 720p. Any idea how to get it higher?