# Most of videos not getting VideoUrl from YouTube

Tags: ios, video, youtube, youtube-api

I am using "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info" to get the video information,thumbnails images,and video URL

To Play the video in Custom video player,but when click on "vevo  channel" video.

its not return any video URL. I also try the different parameter in "get_video_info" api . Example :

[https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=**embedded**&gl=US&ps=default](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=embedded&gl=US&ps=default)

[https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=**detailpage**&gl=US&ps=default](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=detailpage&gl=US&ps=default)

[https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=**vevo**&gl=US&ps=default](https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=vevo&gl=US&ps=default)

https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?hl=en&video_id=0KSOMA3QBU0&eurl=&el=&gl=US&ps=default

**There are many of the videos not getting the video info.
There are following videos, its not getting the video info.**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O1_3zBUKM8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHue-HaXXzg

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PNu_-deVemE

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CevxZvSJLk8

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CEUg7OplvIQ

**but we can play this videos in some of the live application.Example**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tfsapps.playtube2

https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/itube-playlist-management/id789819758?mt=8

https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/itube-free-music-playlists/id866761482?mt=8

How its possible ??

**if I want to play all the videos, so what's the solution ??**

Comment: I also referred to this example --- https://github.com/runmad/RMYouTubeExtractor  

\n but not getting any solution yet

Comment: try this 1)https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/3O1_3zBUKM8?v=2  (2)https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/kHue-HaXXzg?v=2 ans so on ,just insert video no before the query string part

Comment: YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated, some API functions will stop working (and return errors) sooner than other functions. 
https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_deprecated

----->> So we have to find another solution @Agent

Answer (score 1):

The url retrieve videoUrl from YouTube is `https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=/*videoId*/&el=vevo&el=embedded&asv=3&sts=15902`

Here is how to get the videoUrl through videoId. Lua code:

```
-- string.explode(string, separator)
function string.explode(p, d)
  local t, i
  t={}
  i=0
  if(#p == 1) then return {p} end
    while true do
      l=string.find(p,d,i,true)
      if l~=nil then
        table.insert(t, string.sub(p,i,l-1))
        i=l+1
      else
        table.insert(t, string.sub(p,i))
        break
      end
    end
  return t
end

-- string.begin_with
function string.begin_with(str, sub_str)
   return string.find(str, sub_str)==1
end

-- string.url_decode
function string.url_decode(str)
  str = string.gsub (str, "+", " ")
  str = string.gsub (str, "%%(%x%x)", function(h) return string.char(tonumber(h,16)) end)
  str = string.gsub (str, "\r\n", "\n")
  return str
end

-- string.url_query_parameter_map
function string.url_query_parameter_map(str)
    local params_kv = {}
    for k,v in pairs(string.explode(str, "&")) do
        local eqmark_idx = string.find(v, "=")
        if eqmark_idx ~= nil and eqmark_idx > 1 and eqmark_idx < string.len(v) then
            local param_name = string.sub(v, 1, eqmark_idx-1)
            local param_value = string.sub(v, eqmark_idx+1)
            param_name = string.url_decode(param_name)
            param_value = string.url_decode(param_value)
            --print (param_name .." => " .. param_value)
            params_kv[param_name] = param_value
        else
            params_kv[string.url_decode(v)] = ""
        end
    end
    return params_kv
end

function string.ytb_sig_charswap(str, pos)
    local c1 = string.sub(str,1,1)
    local pos2 = (pos-1)%string.len(str)+1--lua has index begun at 1!
    local c2 = string.sub(str,pos2,pos2)

    return c2..string.sub(str,2,pos2-1)..c1..string.sub(str,pos2+1)
end

-- string.ytb_sig_decrypt
function string.ytb_sig_decrypt(str)
    local sig = str
    sig = string.sub(sig, 3)
    sig = string.reverse(sig)
    sig = string.sub(sig, 4)
    sig = string.ytb_sig_charswap(sig, 10)
    sig = string.sub(sig, 4)
    sig = string.ytb_sig_charswap(sig, 44)
    sig = string.sub(sig, 4)
    sig = string.reverse(sig)
    sig = string.ytb_sig_charswap(sig, 24)
    return sig
end

--local s = "YFRHVIIsjrkkiGDtqKXrh847DI5GKDKokWjjgougGDLanT2rw92V6cuXY5BfPGMsaLwgGUYV76wr1T6W"
--print(string.ytb_sig_decrypt(s))

-- define the parser function
-- return: number of video resource, table of video resources, failed reason text.
parse = function (s)
    local params_kv = string.url_query_parameter_map(s)
    -- print(params_kv["fmt_list"]);
    local fmt_list, fmt_stream = params_kv["fmt_list"],  params_kv["url_encoded_fmt_stream_map"]
    local reason, rental_bar = params_kv["reason"], params_kv["ypc_video_rental_bar_text"]

    if (fmt_list == nil or fmt_stream == nil) then
        local reason_text = "reason="
        if (reason ~= nil) then 
            reason_text = reason_text .. reason
        elseif (rental_bar ~= nil) then 
            reason_text = reason_text .. rental_bar
        else 
            reason_text = "reason=This video cannot be played for some unknown reason(unexpected)"
        end
        return 0, {}, reason_text
    end

    print(fmt_list)
    --local fmt_infos = {}
    --for k,v in pairs(string.explode(fmt_list, ",")) do
    --  local fmt_info = string.explode(v, "/")
    --  local v_itag, v_reso = fmt_info[1], fmt_info[2] 
    --  fmt_infos[v_itag]=v_reso
    --  print (v_itag.." => "..v_reso)
    --end

    local stream_n, stream_infos = 0, {}
    for k,v in pairs(string.explode(fmt_stream, ",")) do
        local s_info = string.url_query_parameter_map(v)
        local v_itag, v_url, v_s, v_sig = s_info["itag"], s_info["url"], s_info["s"], s_info["sig"]
        --print (v_itag.." => "..v_url)
        --print ((v_s or "nil").." ~ "..(v_sig or "nil"))
        if (string.find(v_url, "signature=") ~= nil) then
            v_url = v_url
        elseif (v_sig ~= nil) then
            v_url = v_url.."&signature="..v_sig
        elseif (v_s ~= nil) then
            v_url = v_url.."&signature="..string.ytb_sig_decrypt(v_s)
        else
            v_url = v_url
        end
        stream_infos[v_itag] = v_url
        stream_n=stream_n+1
        print (v_itag.." => "..v_url)
    end

    return stream_n, stream_infos, ""
end

-- multiple return values:
-- the first one is script version number.
-- the second one is remote YouTube URL for fetching, with one parameter placeholder "%s".
-- the third one is the parser entry function object.
return "14.3.5", "https://www.youtube.com/get_video_info?video_id=%s&el=vevo&el=embedded&asv=3&sts=15902", parse
```

You can 'translate' it into Objective-C code.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Have you any reference/sourceCode for "get_video_info" API? 
Still I am not getting URL for All the Videos. !

Comment: @V.K. There is no public API for this. This works well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Youtube won't let you play videos that contain rights.
All playable videos will be the ones that are free for use and free of rights.
From July 2021 "get_video_info" returns "410 - gone", I guess that someone in google had a crisis that the videos can be played outside youtube.
need "get_video_info"?
you can use my NuGet https://www.nuget.org/packages/Youtube.VideoInfo

enjoy!

Answer (score -2):

That type of video can only be played when it's embedded on a real website. we don't expose those lists via the API.

This blog post has a bit more detail as well:

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2011/12/understanding-playback-restrictions.html

Comment: No, we can play those videos.some of live application, playing all type of videos. Please check--
https://itunes.apple.com/in/app/itube-playlist-management/id789819758?mt=8

--https://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/itube-free-music-playlists/id866761482?mt=8

-- means we can do this, but I am not getting any solution Yet.