# How to get info about licensed video? | get_video_info

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

I have one problem, when i try to get URL of licensed video i get fail.
Its not return any video URL from licensed video.

For example:
"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O1_3zBUKM8"
When i tried to get url i get fail.

// THIS CODE https://gist.github.com/el3zahaby/9e60f1ae3168c38cc0f0054c15cd6a83

I tried to find solution but there is no answear:
-[Most of videos not getting VideoUrl from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23424908/most-of-videos-not-getting-videourl-from-youtube)
-[How do I get video info for Youtube Vevo Videos?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16555963/how-do-i-get-video-info-for-youtube-vevo-videos)

How its possible ??

if I want to get urls of all the videos, so what's the solution ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `videoId` you're requesting has restrictions for embed it, you wont be able to get further information.

---

In the [request](https://you-link.herokuapp.com/?url=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3O1_3zBUKM8) you get the following result:

```
[
    {
        "itct": "CAEQu2kiEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD",
        "watermark": ",http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_watermark-vflHX6b6E.png,http://s.ytimg.com/yts/img/watermark/youtube_hd_watermark-vflAzLcD6.png",
        "ldpj": "-2",
        "apiary_host_firstparty": "",
        "timestamp": "1550151100",
        "url_encoded_fmt_stream_map": "",
        "apiary_host": "",
        "author": "NaughtyBoyVEVO",
        "video_id": "3O1_3zBUKM8",
        "external_play_video": "1",
        "subreason": "",
        "host_language": "en",
        "root_ve_type": "51879",
        "cr": "US",
        "length_seconds": "244",
        "token": "1",
        "vss_host": "s.youtube.com",
        "csi_page_type": "embed",
        "title": "Naughty Boy - La la la ft. Sam Smith",
        "t": "1",
        "fflags": "html5_min_buffer_to_resume=6&html5_disable_extra_update_resource=true&ad_to_video_use_gel=true&live_fresca_v2=true&html5_streaming_xhr_buffer_mdat=true&html5_license_constraint_delay=5000&disable_client_side_midroll_freq_capping_nonpc=true&html5_request_size_padding_secs=3.0&use_fast_fade_in_0s=true&html5_tight_max_buffer_allowed_impaired_time=0.0&mweb_enable_instream_ui_refresh=true&spacecast_uniplayer_decorate_manifest=true&bulleit_round_up_tsla=true&mweb_undim_skip_button_on_ad_pause=true&html5_connect_timeout_secs=7.0&html5_post_interrupt_readahead=20&html5_subsegment_readahead_target_buffer_health_secs=0.5&tv_html5_bulleit_unify_adinfo=true&html5_platform_minimum_readahead_seconds=0.0&show_thumbnail_on_standard=true&defer_player_config_and_threed_deciders=true&html5_tv_bearer=true&html5_video_tbd_min_kb=0&html5_peak_shave=true&use_survey_skip_in_0s=true&dynamic_ad_break_seek_threshold_sec=0&ima_disable_reset_active_media_load_timeout=true&html5_reason_reporting_migration=true&html5_use_adaptive_live_readahead=true&unplugged_tvhtml5_video_preload_on_focus_delay_ms=0&html5_log_playback_rate_change_killswitch=true&html5_default_ad_gain=0.5&html5_desktop_vr180_allow_panning=true&html5_minimum_readahead_seconds=0.0&html5_ad_no_buffer_abort_after_skippable=true&postroll_notify_time_seconds=5&html5_request_sizing_multiplier=0.8&mweb_bulleit_show_ad_top_bar_for_phones=true&html5_enable_webm_cue_refactor=true&attach_child_on_gel_web=true&log_playback_associated_web=true&html5_live_abr_repredict_fraction=0.0&use_local_interactions_library=true&html5_df_downgrade_thresh=0.0&html5_ignore_public_setPlaybackQuality=true&html5_jumbo_ull_nonstreaming_mffa_ms=4000&html5_get_video_info_timeout_ms=30000&html5_suspend_manifest_on_pause=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_require_whitelist=true&html5_av1_thresh_lcc=0&html5_store_xhr_headers_readable=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_min_load_speed=1.5&desktop_videowall_companion_wta_support=true&set_interstitial_advertisers_question_text=true&bulleit_update_tsla_cookie=true&use_new_skip_icon=true&html5_live_pin_to_tail=true&android_early_fetch_for_autoplay=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_min_buffer_health_secs_on_timeout=0.1&html5_live_4k_more_buffer=true&mweb_playsinline=true&html5_vp9_live_blacklist_edge=true&html5_msi_error_fallback=true&html5_media_fullscreen=true&mweb_muted_autoplay=true&dynamic_ad_break_pause_threshold_sec=0&delay_ads_gvi_call_on_bulleit_living_room_ms=0&html5_deadzone_multiplier=1.0&uniplayer_dbp=true&html5_disable_non_contiguous=true&use_forced_linebreak_preskip_text=true&deprecate_vss_dallas_cache=true&kevlar_miniplayer=true&html5_new_queueing=true&html5_live_ultra_low_latency_bandwidth_window=0.0&website_actions_throttle_percentage=1.0&desktop_cleanup_companion_on_instream_begin=true&enable_website_actions_on_mweb=true&html5_variability_discount=0.5&html5_widevine_hw_secure_all=true&html5_parse_inline_fallback_host=true&html5_live_abr_head_miss_fraction=0.0&preskip_button_style_ads_backend=countdown_next_to_thumbnail&show_thumbnail_behind_ypc_offer_module=true&html5_manifestless_synchronized=true&mpu_visible_threshold_count=2&enable_kevlar_action_companion_cleanup=true&mweb_autonav=true&tvhtml5_min_readbehind_secs=20&mweb_muted_autoplay_animation=shrink&doubleclick_gpt_retagging=true&html5_manifestless_no_redundant_seek_to_head=true&html5_live_normal_latency_bandwidth_window=0.0&show_interstitial_white=true&player_unified_fullscreen_transitions=true&html5_bmffparser_use_fast_read_string=true&html5_maximum_readahead_seconds=0.0&html5_min_readbehind_cap_secs=60&html5_request_size_min_secs=0.0&html5_remove_pause=false&html5_hls_initial_bitrate=0&enable_bulleit_mweb_gaming_ui=true&html5_use_hasAdvanced_for_pbs=true&interaction_click_on_gel_web=true&html5_aspect_from_adaptive_format=true&mweb_playsinline_webview=true&use_always_dimmed_skip_in_bulleit_web=true&html5_disable_move_pssh_to_moov=true&provide_default_wta_reasons=true&html5_probe_media_capabilities=true&html5_manifestless_always_redux=true&fast_autonav_in_background=true&html5_incremental_parser_buffer_duration_secs=1.5&variable_buffer_timeout_ms=0&enable_static_font_size_on_text_only_preview=true&html5_ignore_updates_before_initial_ping=true&show_interstitial_for_3s=true&vmap_enabled_living_room=true&html5_log_hls_video_height_change_as_format_change=true&turn_down_serialized_player_request_for_bulleit_living_room=true&live_readahead_seconds_multiplier=0.8&preskip_countdown_font_size=&html5_max_av_sync_drift=50&enable_live_premieres_vss_live_type_lp=true&web_player_api_logging_fraction=0.01&web_player_assume_format3_available=true&use_touch_events_for_bulleit_mweb=true&html5_inline_video_quality_survey=true&html5_suspend_loader=true&enable_bulleit_for_web_gaming=true&html5_disable_audio_slicing=true&html5_elbow_tracking_tweaks=true&html5_spherical_bicubic_mode=1&player_destroy_old_version=true&html5_use_streaming_xhr_abort_support=true&html5_player_autonav_logging=true&skip_restore_on_abandon_in_bulleit=true&bulleit_web_dim_skip_using_css=true&web_player_response_overlay_parsing=false&html5_dont_predict_end_time_in_past=true&html5_repredict_interval_secs=0.0&html5_vss_live_mode_killswitch=true&bulleit_mimic_ima_player_api_calls=true&visibility_error_html_dump_sample_rate=0.01&html5_playbackmanager_enable_notify_new_drm_info=true&html5_min_upgrade_health=0&use_refreshed_overlay_buttons=true&html5_max_live_dvr_window_plus_margin_secs=46800.0&html5_delay_initial_loading=true&web_player_sentinel=true&variable_load_timeout_ms=0&enable_overlay_hide_timer_fix=true&bulleit_block_player_pause_until_ad_start=true&set_default_wta_if_missing_for_externs=true&dash_manifest_version=5&bulleit_check_overlay_container_before_show=true&defer_playability_status_fillers=true&html5_waiting_before_ended=true&enable_bulleit_for_mweb=true&autoplay_time=8000&enable_bulleit_ve_single_clickthrough=true&html5_no_shadow_env_data_redux=true&html5_adjust_effective_request_size=true&mweb_cougar_big_controls=true&bulleit_disable_preroll_release_on_dispose=true&html5_default_quality_cap=0&web_logging_max_batch=100&enable_survey_ad_info_dialog=true&fixed_padding_skip_button=true&html5_expire_preloaded_players=true&fix_gpt_pos_params=true&html5_min_has_advanced=true&bulleit_send_engage_ping_on_companion_click=true&variable_buffer_timeout_living_room_ms=0&enable_bulleit_mweb_remix_ui=true&lasr_captions_holdback=true&enable_html5_conversion_ve_reporting=true&bulleit_use_touch_events_for_skip=true&desktop_companion_wta_support=true&enable_brand_companion_on_mweb=true&flex_theater_mode=true&youtubei_for_web=true&sdk_ad_prefetch_time_seconds=-1&playready_first_play_expiration=-1&html5_max_buffer_duration=120&max_resolution_for_white_noise=360&desktop_image_companion_wta_support=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_load_speed_check_interval=0.5&html5_manifestless_interpolate=true&html5_enable_widevine_key_rotation=true&enable_embed_autoplay_delay=true&enable_text_ad_overlay_link_fix=true&html5_request_size_max_secs=31&html5_disable_subscribe_new_vis=true&html5_enable_embedded_player_visibility_signals=true&html5_creativeless_vast_on_ima=true&mweb_cougar=true&stop_using_ima_sdk_gpt_request_activity=true&html5_background_cap_idle_secs=60&html5_qoe_bearer=true&html5_stale_dash_manifest_retry_factor=1.0&html5_new_seeking=true&html5_min_secs_between_format_selections=8.0&html5_incremental_parser_coalesce_slice_buffers=true&ad_duration_threshold_for_showing_endcap_seconds=15&bulleit_use_video_end_cuerange_for_completion=true&html5_cut_vss_on_visibility=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_seek_latency_fudge=0.5&embed_new_info_bar=true&html5_sticky_reduces_discount_by=0.0&html5_fludd_suspend=true&web_player_music_visualizer_treatment=fake&html5_no_audio_append_cap=true&html5_autonav_quality_cap=0&html5_ultra_low_latency_streaming_responses=true&ima_video_ad_with_overlay_class_logging_percentage=0.01&html5_frame_accurate_seek_limit=3&html5_subsegment_readahead_timeout_secs=2.0&kevlar_miniplayer_button=true&html5_shrink_live_timestamps=true&enable_mute_ad_endpoint_resolution_on_bulleit=true&html5_release_mediakey_after_load=true&interaction_screen_on_gel_web=true&process_extensions_in_vast_wrappers_for_survey_ads=true&html5_enable_non_diegetic=true&desktop_action_companion_wta_support=true&allow_midrolls_on_watch_resume_in_bulleit=true&enable_composite_ad_player_presentation_for_bulleit=true&html5_get_video_info_promiseajax=true&bulleit_register_cue_range_events_before_ad_init=true&html5_live_low_latency_bandwidth_window=0.0&html5_fallbacks_delay_primary_probes=true&show_countdown_on_bumper=true&embed_api_deprecation=true&android_attestation_flow=yt_player&enable_simple_preview_for_postrolls_html5=true&html5_probe_primary_delay_base_ms=0&html5_new_vis_fullscreen_and_airplay=true&html5_serverside_biscotti_id_wait_ms=1000&enable_instream_companion_on_mweb=true&html5_progressive_fallback=true&call_release_video_in_bulleit=true&html5_exile_broken_instances=true&html5_prefer_server_bwe3=true&enable_prefetch_for_postrolls=true&forced_brand_precap_duration_ms=2000&enable_endcap_on_mweb=true&html5_manifestless_captions=true&www_for_videostats=true&send_html5_api_stats_ads_abandon=true&html5_manifestless_request_prediction=true&disable_new_pause_state3=true&web_player_response_playback_tracking_parsing=true&delay_bulleit_media_load_timer=true&html5_disable_preserve_reference=true&tvhtml5_disable_live_prefetch=true&bulleit_use_http_get_by_default_for_get_midroll_info=true&html5_vp9_live_whitelist=true&vss_dni_delayping=0&html5_serverside_call_server_on_biscotti_timeout=true&html5_preload_media=true&html5_jumbo_ull_subsegment_readahead_target=1.3&bulleit_get_midroll_info_timeout_ms=8000&use_full_timing_library=true&disable_client_side_midroll_freq_capping=true&lasr_captions_holdback_counterfactual_id=23737673&html5_live_disable_dg_pacing=true&html5_pause_video_fix=true&html5_gapless=true&html5_log_rebuffer_events=0&bulleit_publish_external_playback_events=true&html5_max_readahead_bandwidth_cap=0&html5_live_no_streaming_impedance_mismatch=true&skip_ad_button_with_thumbnail=true&use_ima_media_selection_in_bulleit=true&html5_dynamic_readahead_growth_rate=0.0&segment_volume_reporting=true&html5_stop_video_in_cancel_playback=true&html5_serverside_call_server_on_biscotti_error=true&disable_survey_interstitial_for_non_bl_surveys_desktop=true&bulleit_extract_delayed_mpu_on_all_placement_init=true&html5_tight_max_buffer_allowed_bandwidth_stddevs=0.0&html5_streaming_xhr_progress_includes_latest=true&enable_bulleit=true&html5_qoe_intercept=&use_new_style=true&html5_optimality_migration=true&html5_probe_secondary_during_timeout_miss_count=2&html5_manifestless_accurate_sliceinfo=true&fix_bulleit_cue_range_seek=true&playready_on_borg=true&external_fullscreen_with_edu=true&html5_vis_upgrades_are_resizes=true&html5_use_media_capabilities=true&html5_pipeline_manifestless=true&mweb_ios_handle_player_click_by_touch_event=true&bulleit_register_placements_in_order=true&king_crimson_player_redux=true&persist_text_on_preview_button=true&enable_bulleit_lidar_integration=true&enable_afv_div_reset_in_kevlar=true&web_player_native_json=true&html5_subsegment_readahead_min_buffer_health_secs=0.25&midroll_notify_time_seconds=5&html5_background_quality_cap=360&html5_no_placeholder_rollbacks=true&html5_seeking_buffering_only_playing=true&web_player_kaios_autoplay=true&sdk_wrapper_levels_allowed=0&allow_live_autoplay=true&html5_variability_full_discount_thresh=3.0&legacy_autoplay_flag=true&html5_widevine_robustness_strings=true&tvhtml5_yongle_quality_cap=0&add_border_to_bulleit_mweb_skip=true&set_interstitial_start_button=true&html5_bandwidth_window_size=0&html5_streaming_xhr_optimize_lengthless_mp4=true&html5_allowable_liveness_drift_chunks=2&enable_overlays_wta=true&ad_video_end_renderer_duration_milliseconds=7000&html5_variability_no_discount_thresh=1.0&desktop_shopping_companion_wta_support=true&html5_probe_live_using_range=true&html5_firefox_ambisonic_opus=true&html5_av1_thresh=0&html5_adaptation_fix=true&web_player_attestation_auth_headers=true&hide_preskip=true&mweb_add_ad_info_button_on_fullscreen_only_devices=true&html5_max_headm_for_streaming_xhr=0&html5_disable_vp8_only_browsers=true&html5_unrewrite_timestamps=true&html5_quality_cap_min_age_secs=0&web_player_sentinel_is_uniplayer=true&kevlar_allow_multistep_video_init=true&bulleit_use_video_ad_div_as_overlay_container=true&lightweight_watch_video_swf=true&html5_hls_min_video_height=0&live_chunk_readahead=3&bulleit_terminate_ad_when_ending_with_commands=true&html5_manifestless_shrink_timestamps=true&html5_incremental_parser_buffer_extra_bytes=16384&html5_ignore_bad_bitrates=true&html5_min_readbehind_secs=0&html5_restrict_streaming_xhr_on_sqless_requests=true&enable_live_premiere_web_player_indicator=true&html5_jumbo_mobile_subsegment_readahead_target=3.0&html5_readahead_ratelimit=3000&html5_decode_to_texture_cap=true&desktop_player_button_tooltip_with_shortcut=true&html5_hfr_quality_cap=0&low_engagement_player_quality_cap=360&html5_playback_data_migration=true&html5_ad_stats_bearer=true&bulleit_use_cue_video_to_reset_on_stop_ad=true&html5_pipeline_ultra_low_latency=true&bulleit_remove_client_side_midroll_reactivation=true",
        "ucid": "UCarfuQxcly5bNXIezBgbrcQ",
        "csn": "u21lXIblOMu7gwO85p_4Dg",
        "no_get_video_log": "1",
        "cver": "1.20190213",
        "tmi": "1",
        "player_response": "{\"playabilityStatus\":{\"status\":\"UNPLAYABLE\",\"reason\":\"This video is unavailable.\",\"errorScreen\":{\"playerErrorMessageRenderer\":{\"reason\":{\"simpleText\":\"This video is unavailable.\"},\"proceedButton\":{\"buttonRenderer\":{\"style\":\"STYLE_PRIMARY\",\"size\":\"SIZE_DEFAULT\",\"isDisabled\":false,\"text\":{\"simpleText\":\"Watch on YouTube\"},\"trackingParams\":\"CAUQ8FsiEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD\"}},\"thumbnail\":{\"thumbnails\":[{\"url\":\"//s.ytimg.com/yts/img/meh7-vflGevej7.png\",\"width\":140,\"height\":100}]},\"icon\":{\"iconType\":\"ERROR_OUTLINE\"}}}},\"videoDetails\":{\"videoId\":\"3O1_3zBUKM8\",\"title\":\"Naughty Boy - La la la ft. Sam Smith\",\"lengthSeconds\":\"244\",\"keywords\":[\"Naughty\",\"Boy\",\"La\",\"Virgin\",\"Pop\",\"Naughty Boy\",\"NB\",\"Hotel Cabana\",\"HC\",\"Sam Smith\",\"LaLaLa\",\"La La La\",\"The Brits\",\"Brits 2014\",\"Best Single\"],\"channelId\":\"UCarfuQxcly5bNXIezBgbrcQ\",\"isOwnerViewing\":false,\"shortDescription\":\"From Naughty Boy's debut album \\\"Hotel Cabana\\\"\\nAVAILABLE NOW - Download: http://po.st/HCiTunes \\n\\nWatch the Hotel Cabana trailer at http://www.hotel-cabana.com \\n\\nFollow Naughty Boy\\nhttp://www.facebook.com/NBoyMusic \\nhttp://www.twitter.com/naughtyboymusic\\n\\nVideo Directed by Ian Pons Jewell\\n\\nMusic video by Naughty Boy Performing La La La. © 2013\\nNaughty Boy Recordings Ltd, under exclusive licence to Virgin Records Ltd.\",\"isCrawlable\":true,\"thumbnail\":{\"thumbnails\":[{\"url\":\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEiCKgBEF5IWvKriqkDFQgBFQAAAAAYASUAAMhCPQCAokN4AQ==\\u0026rs=AOn4CLDPD4kWz9Ka5D6E7vl5ZLrQi5jfKQ\",\"width\":168,\"height\":94},{\"url\":\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEiCMQBEG5IWvKriqkDFQgBFQAAAAAYASUAAMhCPQCAokN4AQ==\\u0026rs=AOn4CLDANMwzETmpjKzsddzPGEtPpOAW_g\",\"width\":196,\"height\":110},{\"url\":\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCPYBEIoBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=\\u0026rs=AOn4CLD7_I4y877ghNH4H-J5F8npWrtL3g\",\"width\":246,\"height\":138},{\"url\":\"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/hqdefault.jpg?sqp=-oaymwEjCNACELwBSFryq4qpAxUIARUAAAAAGAElAADIQj0AgKJDeAE=\\u0026rs=AOn4CLDmleiZwXsglwaqiwxakgHNs5bVEA\",\"width\":336,\"height\":188}]},\"averageRating\":4.7239766,\"allowRatings\":true,\"viewCount\":\"944097200\",\"author\":\"NaughtyBoyVEVO\",\"isPrivate\":false,\"isUnpluggedCorpus\":false,\"isLiveContent\":false},\"messages\":[{\"mealbarPromoRenderer\":{\"messageTexts\":[{\"runs\":[{\"text\":\"Household sharing included. No complicated set-up. Unlimited DVR storage space. Cancel anytime.\"}]}],\"actionButton\":{\"buttonRenderer\":{\"style\":\"STYLE_PRIMARY\",\"size\":\"SIZE_DEFAULT\",\"text\":{\"runs\":[{\"text\":\"Try it free\"}]},\"navigationEndpoint\":{\"clickTrackingParams\":\"CAQQ7G8iEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD\",\"urlEndpoint\":{\"url\":\"https://tv.youtube.com/?utm_source=dmea\\u0026utm_medium=np\\u0026utm_campaign=dmea_evglo19h\\u0026pid=dmea-acq-u-2evgloh\"}},\"trackingParams\":\"CAQQ7G8iEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD\"}},\"dismissButton\":{\"buttonRenderer\":{\"style\":\"STYLE_BLUE_TEXT\",\"size\":\"SIZE_DEFAULT\",\"text\":{\"runs\":[{\"text\":\"No thanks\"}]},\"serviceEndpoint\":{\"clickTrackingParams\":\"CAMQ7W8iEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD\",\"feedbackEndpoint\":{\"feedbackToken\":\"AB9zfpJ28dV1uTmBv3-KAOkp1B4LWrc0l7aDyhooLNgKoKOIb4YIljQzt_xpRIY4s3FdAHP7Y9Fs82kdPNynErGmtWpoN08N_tB89C_iXbmVfGX2cBsVI9jYefRjrXMvrCsLYF9EB6GdbFkJG0QRV_d6yweeO8afwg\",\"uiActions\":{\"hideEnclosingContainer\":true}}},\"trackingParams\":\"CAMQ7W8iEwjGrqPtqrvgAhXL3WAKHTzzB-8op5UD\"}},\"triggerCondition\":\"TRIGGER_CONDITION_POST_AD\",\"style\":\"STYLE_MESSAGE\",\"trackingParams\":\"CAIQ42kYACITCMauo-2qu-ACFcvdYAodPPMH7yinlQM=\",\"impressionEndpoints\":[{\"clickTrackingParams\":\"CAIQ42kYACITCMauo-2qu-ACFcvdYAodPPMH7yinlQM=\",\"feedbackEndpoint\":{\"feedbackToken\":\"AB9zfpI_vFbKZTz2susb8fZ1ZN5ssfCrX8Yvphgc1zC6CZbPuuJBBSORpY_gOQMva2RzszXoLTPHxWk1QpPiklJ_Us4Dwogy2x2O8whkiigVfJ262DjwN-Cnv5S5qqZK47TOsy-lbTMkZAmNkQpbFnLbELAvObwWOw\",\"uiActions\":{\"hideEnclosingContainer\":false}}}],\"isVisible\":true,\"messageTitle\":{\"runs\":[{\"text\":\"YouTube TV - No long term contract\"}]}}}],\"adSafetyReason\":{\"isEmbed\":true,\"isRemarketingEnabled\":true,\"isFocEnabled\":true}}",
        "innertube_api_key": "AIzaSyAO_FJ2SlqU8Q4STEHLGCilw_Y9_11qcW8",
        "idpj": "-2",
        "c": "WEB",
        "enablecsi": "1",
        "account_playback_token": "QUFFLUhqbFloSXVCbmZUOHI2ZkJPZ1VxV252MEt6RXlGd3xBQ3Jtc0ttWEtPeDdiVVB1akZxdVRvbS1PanZQMVZzcXdXaGNPa1F6d2dINWtoWXFpaEVkTnhycm1pMWZwaEZ0MHd1ckNnZXFWLXVTWjVTb3ZyM210bkhjU0tObEpNZjM4d3U0NjVnaDBfQ0JfM3g4VGs5LWRadw==",
        "player_error_log_fraction": "1.0",
        "fexp": "23710476,23733013,23735285,23735347,23736684,23737832,23744176,23750564,23751767,23752869,23755886,23755898,23758087,23758204,23759539,23760558,23761607,23762063,23762649,23770908,23775608,23776321,23779065,23780478,23783369,23783454,23785342,23787227,23788290,23788839,23789247,23789643,23791498,23791618,23791648,23792619,23794641,23794899,23795144,9449243,9452649,9471239,9474461,9475671,9479112",
        "errorcode": "150",
        "innertube_api_version": "v1",
        "gapi_hint_params": "m;/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.Qyhlf-E27OQ.O/rt=j/d=1/rs=AHpOoo_77KcTN4WVhdQMqIfKBMTqlRW8yg/m=__features__",
        "fmt_list": "",
        "thumbnail_url": "http://i.ytimg.com/vi/3O1_3zBUKM8/default.jpg",
        "reason": "This video is unavailable.",
        "hl": "en_US",
        "xhr_apiary_host": "youtubei.youtube.com",
        "errordetail": "0",
        "innertube_context_client_version": "1.20190213",
        "status": "fail",
        "error": true,
        "instagram": "egy.js",
        "apiMadeBy": "El-zahaby"
    }
]
```

Check closely the **`reason`** and **`status`** properties - the **`player_response`** property might be useful too.

```
"reason": "This video is unavailable.",
"status": "fail",
```

Comment: Thanks for answear. But if look at this app: [FireTube](https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/folders/0BybxZFtPcHnUZDh2VnFlRU9FMkk), you will see that it gets all info about any video. So how this app do this, as this is the only way to get info, we cant get info from API or somewhere else..

Comment: @MaxDev I don't know about how FireTube works, but, maybe is because they have some paid acces to YouTube API or they might be web-scraping, again, this is justa a guess...

Comment: Thank you for your's answear!